# Determine the element's type of a buffer in the Metal Shader Language

Tags: metal

I use a codegen for generating declarations of Metal shaders and sometimes I do not know the exact types of objects that are passed to shaders.

E.g. I would have this declaration generated automatically:

```cpp
vertex VertexOut vertexShader(constant Element *array [[buffer(0)]])
```

When I try to get the element's type of the array I get the error from the compiler:

```cpp
using T = metal::remove_reference_t<decltype( *array )>;
T test;// <-- ERROR! "Automatic variable qualified with an address space"
```

Is this possible to "erase" the address space from the type?

What is the best way of getting the type of an array's element in Metal (if it's possible at all)?

Comment: I think this is happening because remove_reference is defined as `template <typename T>
struct remove_reference<constant T &>
{
  typedef constant T type;
};` So you get a `T` that's actually `constant Element`, which doesn't make sense since it's a variable and not a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment, I think the problem is that `remove_reference` does exactly what it says: it removes reference, while still leaving the type qualified. You can not declare a variable in `device` or `constant` space, so you also need to remove the address space qualifier, similar to how `remove_cv_t` works. I've written up a couple templates to show you what I mean:

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_address_space
{
  typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_address_space<device T>
{
  typedef T type;
};
template <typename T>
struct remove_address_space<constant T>
{
  typedef T type;
};
```

and then you would use it like

```
using T = remove_address_space<metal::remove_reference_t<decltype( *array )>>::type;
```

Keep in mind that metal has a lot of address spaces, but for the purposes of writing entry points to functions, I think only the `device` and `constant` are relevant.